# reading files with special characters from a zipfile

Tags: java, stream, zip

My code reads files from a zipfile , which works fine except for files with special characters. Problematic character is 'è' ( See my code fère_champenoise )

```
String works="(3/(3)_juno.jpa";
     String sdoesntwork="ba/battle of fère_champenoise.jpa";

    ZipFile file1 = null;
    try {
      file1 = new ZipFile(sZipFileOld);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Could not open zip file " + sZipFileOld + ": " + e);

    }

    try {
        file1.getInputStream(file1.getEntry(sdoesntwork));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(sdoesntwork + ": IO Error " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it throws an error but doesn't go throught the exception handler:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at ZipCompare.main(ZipCompare.java:56)
```

Any Solutions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When constructing the zipfile, explicitly specifying the encoding:  `file1 = new ZipFile(sZipFileOld, Charset.forName("IBM437"));`

Zip files doesn't use the default UTF-8 encoding for special characters

Comment: My java.util.zip.ZipFile Class does not allow a second parameter.

Comment: @user1344545 are you using Java 7? as the is a [`ZipFile(File,
       Charset )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#ZipFile(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) constructor in java7

Comment: @user1344545 then you will have to modify `ZipInputStream` as described in http://scn.sap.com/people/thilo.brandt/blog/2010/01/18/handling-zip-file-entries-with-special-characters-and-cp437-encoding

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me out. Just updated to Java 7 and constructor has 2 Parameters now. Also my problem is solved. So happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specify an encoding, UTF-8 probably. Something like this:

```
 final InputStream in = new InputStreamReader(file1.getInputStream(file1.getEntry(sdoesntwork)), "utf-8");
```

Make sure you remember to close this in a finally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `file1.getEntry(sdoesntwork)` returns null because it does not find that entry.
If you are sure this name is correct, then try to use:

```
file1 = new ZipFile(sZipFileOld,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: My java.util.zip.ZipFile Class does not allow a second parameter.

Comment: This constructor is only in Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't go through your exception handler because is another type of exception, Null pointer exception is thrown because the entry is not found. You should check how or with which Charset the file has been define.

Answer (score 0):

file1 = new ZipFile(sZipFileOld,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

charset - The charset to be used to decode the ZIP entry name and comment (ignored if the  language encoding bit of the ZIP entry's general purpose bit flag is set).

if the zip entry and its comment is ASCII, it is not necessary to use this way to construct the ZipFile.